# Full image instead of thumbnail

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a shop page on [this website](https://www.gamebrewer.com/).

I will explain my problem using the very first image in the top left as example, although it applies to all of them.

If you hover over the first image (Gentes Deluxified English) you see an incomplete picture like this:

src= ".../Gentes-board-DLX-20180123**-200x267**.jpg"

[image: example image gentes deluxified]

This image actually cuts of parts of the images to the left and right. The full image is like this:

src= " .../Gentes-board-DLX-20180123.jpg"
[image: full image gentes deluxified]

So we want to change the thumbnail image to the full image, or keep the original ratio of the image. This needs to work for all images and the ones added in the future.

Is this fixable with css?

I already spent a lot of time looking at the source code of woocommerce to find the file that creates the page that uses the thumbnail images. I can't find that file. Where should I look for the source code files? And what should I change in these source files?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of Woo commerce and found the parameter for cropping thumbnails for you.
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-regenerate-images.php

Add this

```
$crop = false;
```

after line 318:

```
private static function get_image( $fullsizepath, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $crop ) {
```